# Why is close() implemented in InputStream/OutputStream?

Tags: java, abstraction

It make sense to see `close()` as non-core functionality of stream objects. This is the reason this method is placed in `interface Closeable`. One evidence is that `class ByteArrayInputStream` does not require the `close()` operation.

```
public abstract class InputStream implements Closeable {}

public abstract class OutputStream implements Closeable, Flushable {}
```

Based on the above definitions my observation is that `interface Closeable` should not be implemented by `abstract class InputStream/OutputStream`; it has to be left to concrete sub-classes (like `class FileInputStream`) to implement it.

### [image]

Do you think my understanding is correct?

Comment: it is part of it, the closeable interface is a retro fit

Comment: Do we need to introduce `interface Closeable` to retrofit?

Comment: Does `class ByteArrayInputStream` require `close()` operation? I guess `close()` operation is mainly required when you communicate via file descriptors of the process.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Only correction for the current impl could be, `interface Closeable` should have been implemented by concrete sub classes of `abstract class InputStream` instead of `InputStream` itself implementing it.

Answer (score 6):

***Just my two cents.*** The goal of this answer is to give some thoughts and attract more answers, not trying to sound like definitive or even informative.

---

**Why are streams abstract base classes instead of interfaces?**

- It is possible to define a strictly minimal interface.

  - Typically this consists of: read, write, seek, tell (returns current file position), get length, truncate (reduce file size), close.
- However, to make the stream implementation convenient to use, a lot of helper methods on the class would be needed.

  - Without these helper methods, it would make the programming language impractical, because it would then be too troublesome to use streams as a fundamental feature of the standard library.
  - These helper methods make use of the minimal interface.
  - Typically, default (standard) implementations can be provided for these helper methods, that would completely satisfy the needs most of the time.
  - Therefore, abstract base classes are used to provide these default helper method implementations to improve the usability of the standard library.

---

**Is the close() method fundamental to the operation of streams?**

Contrary to your point of view, I would argue that streams that do not require closing is the minority, rather than majority.

- File system handles
- Operating-system owned resources, such as:

  - Sockets
  - Pipes
  - Operating-system managed shared memory (as opposed to JVM-managed memory)
- Database connections

To put it bluntly,

- It appears that array-backed streams are the ***only*** kind of streams that do not require explicit closing.

---

**Does the cost-benefit analysis favor the inclusion of the close() method into the stream interface?**

It seems so. For streams that do not require explicit closing, it is ***harmless*** to require it to provide a trivial `close()` method that does nothing.

Similar observation can be found in the C# language, where it is common to see interfaces that [subtype from](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping)  `IDisposable`.

---

**Would the failure to include the close() method in the stream interface cause extraordinary harm to implementations that require it?**

Yes. Not having it on the interface, or splitting it out to a second `Closeable` interface would cause extraordinary harm.

In the first code snippet below, suppose `InputStream` does not contain the `close()` method. Here is what the code would look like:

```
public void parseAndCloseStream(InputStream strm) throws IOException
{
    if (strm == null) { /* ... to avoid NPE inside finally */ }
    try
    {
        // read from stream
    }
    finally
    {
        if (strm instanceof Closeable)
        {
            Closeable c = (Closeable)strm;
            c.close();
        }
    }
}
```

In other words, because the omission implies that "not every InputStream is a Closeable", any consumer of any InputStream instance now has the additional responsibility to check whether the instance is indeed Closeable.

The `try-with` pattern would then also require more code, because you cannot use an InputStream there unless you can cast it into a Closeable.

---

**Is it a violation of Interface Segregation Principle?**

No.

- If a method is fundamental to the operation for the majority of implementation, it makes sense to require it.
- Likewise, if a method is cohesive with the rest of the methods in that interface (i.e. common-sense for its inclusion), it is not a violation.

Specifically, Interface Segregation Principle **does not** require:

- Does not require an interface to be minimal; even though there are benefits for keeping an interface small and simple.
- Does not require one to separate out all orthogonal facets of an interface, if doing so will cause more harm than good (great inconvenience).

Comment: May be this would help you http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/262706/why-liste-is-an-interface-but-not-abstract-class answer your first question.

Comment: @overexchange I agree that traits would be more suitable for adding common peripheral behaviors to concrete implementations of an interface.

Comment: for your second question, there is no majority/minority. it is core and peripheral behaviour. `close()` is peripheral.

Comment: @overexchange you have not yet provided any convincing argument that `close()` is peripheral and not core.

Comment: If there is a programming language that imposes a single-ownership requirement for objects that require `Closeable`, (that is, the same owner object must create, own, and close the closeable object), then `close()` would become part of the language, and then there would be no need to include this method on the stream interface. But Java is not such a language.

Comment: In the query i mentioned, why close() is peripheral.

Comment: scenario of `interface Closeable` discussed in this query can be compared with `interface ActionListener` that is implemented by user subclasses of `class JFrame` but not `JFrame` itself.